# Scaled Prediction Variance for more than 7 factors

Tags: rsm

How can I calculate scaled prediction variance (SPV) using vdg package of central composite design and Box-Behnken Design for more than 7 factors?

When I import more than 7-factor datasets of BBD, it gives a 'kvar1' object not found.
Error in Vdgraph::Vdgraph(ccd1sph_matrix) : object 'kvar1' not found